# Hard inequality with cos() and sin()

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Let $m,n$ be natural numbers and let $\alpha_{ij}$ be reals. For each $i=1,2,...,m$; $j=1,2,...,n$. Show that:

$\displaystyle
\prod_{j=1}^{n}\left(1-\prod_{i=1}^{m}\cos^2 \alpha_{ij}\right)+
\prod_{i=1}^{m}\left(1-\prod_{j=1}^{n}\sin^2 \alpha_{ij}\right)\ge 1$

Comment: english please? I have no idea what sean or $sen^{2}$ mean

Comment: $\mathrm{sen}(\cdot)$ is simply $\mathrm{sin}(\cdot)$, but yes this site uses English.

Comment: @Eff oh i see. strange because in the title s/he wrote $\sin$,

Comment: Looks like some probabilistic interpretation might help here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X_{ij}$ be independent random variables with
$$P(X_{ij}=0)=\cos^2\alpha_{ij},$$
$$P(X_{ij}=1)=\sin^2\alpha_{ij}.$$
Let $A$ be the event $(\exists i)(\forall j)(X_{ij}=1)$ and $B$ the event $(\exists j)(\forall i)(X_{ij}=0)$. These are mutually exclusive, so
$$
  P(A\cap B)=0.
$$
We have
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  P(A)&=&1-P(\neg A)\\
    &=&1-P\left((\forall i)(\exists j)(X_{ij}=0)\right)\\
    &=&1-\prod_iP\left((\exists j)(X_{ij}=0)\right)\\
    &=&1-\prod_i\left(1-P((\forall j)(X_{ij}=1))\right)\\
    &=&1-\prod_i\left(1-\prod_j P(X_{ij}=1)\right)\\
    &=&1-\prod_i\left(1-\prod_j\sin^2\alpha_{ij}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Similarly
$$
  P(B)=1-\prod_j\left(1-\prod_i\cos^2\alpha_{ij}\right).
$$
Hence
$$
  \prod_j\left(1-\prod_i\cos^2\alpha_{ij}\right)+\prod_i\left(1-\prod_j\sin^2\alpha_{ij}\right)
    =2-P(A)-P(B).
$$
But $1\geq P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)$, so the RHS is $\geq1$.

Comment: Very nice explanation. :-) (+1)